# ReactiveUI not responding to changes in test (with Autofixture)

Tags: reactiveui, autofixture

Look at the following codes (simple ones)

```
public class NewEventViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> isSendVisible;
    public bool IsSendVisible
    {
        get { return isSendVisible.Value; }
    }

    private ReactiveList<string> users;

    public ReactiveList<string> Users
    {
        get { return this.users; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref users, value); }
    }

    public NewEventViewModel()
    {

        Users = new ReactiveList<string>(new List<string>())
        {
            ChangeTrackingEnabled = true
        };

        Users.CountChanged
            .Select(x => x > 0)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsSendVisible, out isSendVisible);
        //Users.Add("commented");
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void ShouldBeVisibleWhenIsAtLeastOneUser()
    {
        //var sut = new NewEventViewModel();
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var sut = fixture.Create<NewEventViewModel>();
        sut.Users.Add("something");
        sut.IsSendVisible.ShouldBeTrue();
    }
```

The test fails... but when I uncomment the line from ViewModel, it passes.

Looks like the test is ignoring changes to Users. It works when I create the sut manually (new NewEventViewModel()). Why is AutoFixture breaking the test in such a strange way? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you use `fixture.Create`, by default AutoFixture assigns values to all writable public properties and fields. This included inherited members. Is there a member on the base class that could turn off the event flow?

Comment: No, there are only getters and public events. Does AutoFixture work on other thread?

Comment: No, it doesn't. What happens if you create `sut` with `fixture.Build<NewEventViewModel>().OmitAutoProperties().Create()`?

Comment: Thanks it works! You can respond so others will find the answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
fixture.Build<NewEventViewModel>().OmitAutoProperties().Create()
```

to temporarily turn off auto-properties.